# How to compare types in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to test for the "type" parameter:

```
class MyConverter : Converter.Factory() {

    override fun responseBodyConverter(
        type: Type,
        annotations: Array<Annotation>,
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): Converter<ResponseBody, *> {
        if (type is UserSettings) // Compiler complains of incompatible types
            return HtmlConverter.INSTANCE
        else
            return null
    }

    class HtmlConverter : Converter<ResponseBody, UserSettings> {
        companion object {
            val INSTANCE = HtmlConverter()
        }
    }
}
```

But the line of code:

```
if (type is UserSettings)
```

gives me a compile error indicating that "type is incompatible with UserSettings"

But if I print type.toString() to the Log, it shows the type is UserSettings. So I don't understand what the issue is. Similar Java code works fine but this Kotlin code does not. I must be doing something wrong in Kotlin.

Comment: You can only use an `is` check to test an *instance* for being of a certain type. Here, you have an object that clearly does not belong to the type `UserSettings`, it is a `Type` instance. Check the `Type`'s API for something like `isSubtype`. What library does `Type` come from, by the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing the reflection type with the actual class type. `is` Tests on the actual class while `java.lang.reflect.Type` is something different. Furthermore, `Type` is not a parent class of UserSettings nor is it implementing the interface.

If you want to test whether your type references UserSettings, you have to compare using `Type::getTypeName` or by querying the type name of UserSettings. The following code should work:

```
if(type == UserSettings::class.java)
    return HtmlConverter.INSTANCE
else
    return null
```